# Getting distinct rows usin Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq, ado.net

I am grouping Data using linq as you can see from the following code, after group i want to interate over the group data and add to another table.

But I am only getting InvoiceHeader.Key, I dont know how to get other fields

```
        DataTable VendorInvoiceStagingTable;
        DataTable VendorInvoiceTable;
        VendorInvoiceStagingTable = new Program().ReadExcelFile(@"C:\Users\huzaifa.gain\Desktop\Vendor invoice import - sample data set.xlsx", "Sheet2");
        var InvoiceHeadercollection = from row in VendorInvoiceStagingTable.AsEnumerable()
                            group row by row.Field<string>(VendInvoice.Number) into grp
                            select grp;




         VendorInvoiceTable =  new Program().CreateHeader();
         foreach (var InvoiceHeader in InvoiceHeadercollection)
        {

         VendorInvoiceTable.Rows.Add(InvoiceHeader.Key, .....


        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `InvoiceHeader` is an [`IGrouping`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344977.aspx) which implements `IEnumerable` you can simply enumerate the items in the group, so you can just use a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach (var InvoiceHeader in InvoiceHeadercollection)
{
  foreach(var row in InvoiceHeader)
      VendorInvoiceTable.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Comment: @huzaifa it would help to answer your question if you Stated why it Will not work for you. The post you refer to has a different problem

Comment: It throws exception. unable to cast, you can see the exception in the image attached to link

Comment: this shouldn't throw an exception, did you try it at all? note that there's an inner loop where we enumerate the rows, and there's no cast to DataRow in the outer loop.